# Pattern matching for characters, comma and semicolon

Tags: regex

I am trying to pattern match against a textbox input field.

The entered text should consist of only characters separated by a ',' or a ';' followed by an optional space.

Example: `Jane, Doe`, `Jane,Doe`, `Jane,Doe; Jack,Black` and `Jane,Doe;Jack,Black` are valid. But `Jane Doe`, `(leading space)Jane` and `Doe(trailing space)` are invalid.

The current pattern I have is,
`/^[A-Za-z]+(,;)?$/`

Please help.

Comment: What's the problem with `Jane Doe`? It seems to fit your rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
/^[A-Za-z]+([,;]\s?[A-Za-z]+)*$/
```

Comment: `Jane, Doe` will not satisfy this one. Will it?

Comment: It shouldn't do - the semi-colon or comma are required

Comment: What about return statements?
`Jane, Doe;(return)Jack, Black`

Also, `Jane, Doe`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by return statements. You could make it work with any whitespace by changing the space in the regex to \s

Comment: Its actually not working. If `name` is `Jan`, `name.match(pattern)` returns null. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: ASP.Net
`function checkName(name) {
            var charPattern = "/^[A-Za-z]+([,;]\s?[A-Za-z]+)*$/";
            var res = name.match(charPattern);
            return true;
        }`

Comment: The regex seems to be fine. There is something wrong with the above js function. Can't seem to figure out what though.

Comment: You just need to remove the quotes around the regex.

Comment: Thanks! Another addition I would like to make is to ensure that each name has atleast three letters. Meaning, `Jane, Doe; Ja` should not satisfy while `Jane, Doe; Jac` should. Is there a way to do this?
Note: This does not apply for the comma.

Comment: You could just change both `+` characters to `{3,}`. You should probably start a new question for any other additions.

Comment: According to the modification suggested, `Jane, Do; Jane` will not be satisfied. I want the entire name, i.e., Every string separated by `;` should have atleast 3 characters and NOT each word. Sorry for the miscommunication.

Answer (score 2):

Try with following regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+([,;] ?[a-zA-Z]+)*$/
```

Comment: `Jane, Doe` will not satisfy this one. Will it?